# Database schema for Employee Schedule

Tags: php, mysql, schema

I'm trying to create schedule table for each employees in my database, is it right to store **everyday schedule** for each employee in the database? my other idea is just to store day-off of each employees to minimize data in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You should save scheduled for all employee daily as it help to fetch report.

If there is iteration in data then you save as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

is it right to store everyday schedule for each employee in the database? yes if you want to get exact data

you may add another table connected to employee for example

employee -> attendance

this attendance table have the data's of scheduled table so it is like 1 employee has many attendance.

Comment: thats it, the word attendance is what i need. but, is it gonna be attendance for the whole year is just fine for my database schema?

Comment: @jp.palubs yes no problem if you have good table schema and indexing of tables